# Setting up Transitions/Segues from different elements of a Table View using Storyboards

Tags: ios5, storyboard, segue, xcode-storyboard

I believe my question is relatively basic but I still haven't found something that directly answers it. I'm trying to learn Objective C and iOS Programming using Storyboards and am in the process of building my first app now. The way I have it set up right now is, I have a Navigation Controller that goes to a Table View controller (controller A). I'm passing an array to my table view and I have the disclosure indicators on the different elements in my array.  I also have a second different view controller (controller B) with a table view in it. I want different elements of controller A to transition to different views/controllers etc. I'm familiar with the concept of segues and the prepareForsegue method however, I dont need prepareforsegue here since I'm not really passing anything to the next screen. I just want to be able to click different elements of my Table View in controller A to bring me different views (i.e like controller B and other views that I plan to build). Is there something I'm not seeing or do I need to fundamentally change my design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking of creating different prototyped cells?

Here's how I understand your question:
I have two (or more) different kinds of cells where I know the view to which they would transition beforehand (when your table queries the delegate).
I would like those cells to go to different controllers rather than the same controller.

If this is right, check it out:

- Create a new UITableViewCell in the table by dragging from your kit
  of UI objects.
- Give each cell a reuse Identifier
- [image: List item]
- Control+Click and drag to your target view controller
- You'll get a popup asking what type of segue and what UI object triggers the segue
- [image: List item]
- Then you'll see two segue indicators leaving your UITableViewController
- Finally, make sure you dequeue the right type of cell:

  ```
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellReuseIDA"];
  return cell;
  ```